# Difference between Cardioid and Circle

Tags: geometry

I have two curves:
   $$x^2+y^2=4$$
and...
   $$(x^2+y^2)=(x+x^2+y^2)^2$$
which, when plotted, form a cardioid pattern within a circle.

I would like to know how to calculate and plot the difference between these two curves. I'm not a student of maths and this isn't someone's homework. I'm a sound recording engineer and these curves represent microphone pickup-patterns. I finished High School maths and my university course had a maths component, but I'm very much *not* a professional when it comes to alegebra - I probably know enough to be ... well ... slightly intimidating to a small furry rodent.

I note that when reducing these equations for ... say 'y' we are left with +/- operators which is where I think I am getting stuck.

I am attempting to prove that the theoretical combination of two "cardioid" microphones placed back-to-back (with one phase inverted) can be the same as a "figure of 8" microphone pattern.

How would I go about this?

Comment: What do you mean by "*the difference between these two curves*" - distance, areas, in what sense?This is a [sample plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D1,+x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D(x%2Bx%5E2%2By%5E2)%5E2) for $a=1$.

Comment: ok I have edited the equations to remove 'a' and to achieve the required plots. I am attempting to see what the result of "subtracting" the cardioid curve from the "circle' would be.   http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D4,+x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D(x%2Bx%5E2%2By%5E2)%5E2 I am pretty sure the result is another cardioid curve facing the other way, but would like to be able to prove this alegebraically.

Comment: Sorry, still not clear on what you mean by subtracting two curves. Just as an example, if you subtracted a circle from a square, what would the result be or look like?

Comment: yeah pretty much, but I would also like to be able to prove that the resultant curve is going to be an opposite facing cardioid - if possible.

Comment: You are asking "I am attempting to prove that the theoretical combination of two "cardioid" microphones placed back-to-back (with one phase inverted) can be the same as a "figure of 8" microphone pattern". This is not a well-defined question for mathematicians, but may well be for one sound engineers or physicists.Can you explain further?

Comment: The ideal microphone patterns I am interested in are described by algebraic equations. Most sound engineers like myself are not as hot-to-trot with algebra as we would like - hence my humble visit to your eminent domain. I have attempted to put it in language more familiar to mathematicians, but I fear my expertise may be limited - hence my plea for help.

Comment: @Mark What *is* the result of "*subtracting*" two curves? Are you looking for a number, a function, another closed curve? Nobody is faulting you for not speaking pure math language, but it's simply hard to understand what the question actually means. P.S. One cardioid facing the other way can be obtained by replacing $x \mapsto -x$ like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D4,+x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D(x%2Bx%5E2%2By%5E2)%5E2,+x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D(-x%2Bx%5E2%2By%5E2)%5E2) but I don't know how that factors into the question.

Comment: a closed curve and a function would be .... just great.

Comment: the reverse facing curve looks like:    $$(x^2+y^2)=(-x+x^2+y^2)^2$$ but I am not sure how to prove the result

Comment: @Mark The transformation $x \mapsto -x$ is the symmetry across the $y$ axis, so when you replace $x$ with $-x$ in the equation you get the symmetrical curve.

Answer (score 2):

The way to combine the curve is by adding the intensities in the direction considered. Hence, in polar coordinates, $\rho=f(\theta)$ and $\rho=g(\theta)$ give $\rho=f(\theta)+g(\theta)$.

In polar coordinates, the cardoid is

$$\rho=\cos\theta+1.$$

Then two back-to-back cardioids will respond like the sum

$$\rho=\cos\theta+1+\cos(\theta+\pi)+1=2,$$ which is a circle !

If the two microphones are isolated by a plane so that only one of them is excited (or electronics selects the one that gives the most power), the curve becomes

$$\rho=|\cos\theta|+1,$$ not exactly an $8$ curve.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Yves - you've picked up on what I am trying to do here. I am very interested in what we might see if we take into account the small rearward lobes of the cardioid patterns. Are these being discarded somehow in the blue inner plot above?

Comment: @Mark: they are completely discarded as by hypothesis only one microphone is active at a time. This is a theoretical situation anyway, which makes sense only when the source of sound comes from a single direction.

Comment: Actually the situation in reality is that both capsules are active at all times. The off-axis response of the rearward facing microphone is only (theoretically) nulled along the x axis. Does this make a big difference to the calculations? It is certainly much easier to understand doing this with a polar equation.

Comment: @Mark: hem, I said it and drew it, you get a circle, i.e. a perfect omni pattern.

Comment: OK - thanks mate. So those lines in the equation you are using...
    $$|cos(theta)|$$
does that restrict the result to positive numbers? - what symbol would be used to restrict the "plane" to a Y-Axis? Your equation here is slicing along the X-Axis? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polar+plot+%CF%81%3D%7Ccos%CE%B8%7C%2B1,%CF%81%3D%7Ccos(%CE%B8%2Bpi)%7C%2B1 - probably should explain that the "on-axis" position for these cardioids is along the X-Axis

Comment: @Mark: no, it's not exactly restricting to positive numbers. Actually I am taking the largest of $\cos\theta+1$ and $\cos(\theta+\pi)+1$, which turns out to be $|\cos\theta|+1$. The change from one mike to the other occurs on the Y axis, when the two signals are equal. Your request doesn't fit with this, I can't answer.

Comment: Thankyou for your help - you've brought my understanding of this on massively. Much appreciated. Merci.